# where clause in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
select: 'Category',
from: '1knKsUyo265x23IBqT6ovIqRdF905uIejBMmv6XI',
where: "'Category' = 'Shopping'" 
},
});
```

layer.setMap(map);

I want to add one more spatial condition with WHERE clause

```
'ST_INTERSECTS(LATITUDE, Circle(LatLng(49.248703,-123.101305), 5000))'
```

Both of them work perfectly but separately. Can anyone please help me combing those two queries under WHERE clause?

Comment: `where: "'Category' = 'Shopping' AND ST_INTERSECTS(LATITUDE, Circle(LatLng("+ x +","+ y +"),"+ radiusm +"))"`

Comment: I have tried it but doesn't work...:(

Comment: Impossible to tell you why without knowing the tableid and the values of x,y and radiusm.  Check the spelling of the column-names(they are case-sensitive)

Comment: It works separately so no chance of spelling mistake. I have added tableid and lat long value

layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
    select: 'Category',
    from: '1knKsUyo265x23IBqT6ovIqRdF905uIejBMmv6XI',
    where: "'Category' = 'Shopping'" 
    },
    });
layer.setMap(map);

'ST_INTERSECTS(LATITUDE, Circle(LatLng(49.248703,-123.101305), 5000))'

Comment: As posted by geocodezip, it works. When it doesn't work for you show us your page and we may tell you what is wrong

Comment: remove the trailing comma after the query, or it will fail in some IE-versions

Comment: Following worked for me: 

where: Category = 'Shopping' AND ST_INTERSECTS(LATITUDE, Circle(LatLng("+ x +","+ y +"),"+ radiusm +"))"

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation LATLNG should be capitalized (and CIRCLE).

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select

This works for me:

```
Category = 'Shopping' AND ST_INTERSECTS(LATITUDE, CIRCLE(LATLNG(49.248703,-123.101305), 5000))
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoD.html?lat=49.248755&lng=-123.122818&zoom=11&type=m&tableid=1knKsUyo265x23IBqT6ovIqRdF905uIejBMmv6XI&tablequery=LATITUDE&tablewhere=Category%20%3D%20%27Shopping%27%20AND%20ST_INTERSECTS%28LATITUDE%2C%20CIRCLE%28LATLNG%2849.248703%2C-123.101305%29%2C%205000%29%29)